# How do I write an IF ELSE statement that my arithmetic operators don't run if the display.innerHTML is empty?

Tags: javascript

```
    let operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]')
    let numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
    
    let display = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]')
    display.innerHTML = '';
    
    const displayValue = function () {
      numberButtons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
          console.log(display.innerHTML)
          display.innerHTML += button.innerHTML;
        })
      });
    
      operationButtons.forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', () => {
          console.log(display.innerHTML)
          display.innerHTML += item.innerHTML;
        })
      });
    }
    
    displayValue();
    
    if (display.innerHTML == '') {
      operationButtons.innerHTML = '';
    } else {
      return 0
    }
```

I'm new to Javascript and am trying to create Calculator. I don't want the arithmetic operators to appear on the display if there's no numbers already there. How do I do that?

Comment: `if (display.innerHTML != '') display.innerHTML += item.innerHTML;`

Answer (score 1):

You could just write the if condition within the operationButtons' click listenrs.

```
let operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]')
let numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')

let display = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]')
display.innerHTML = '';

const displayValue = function () {
  numberButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log(display.innerHTML)
      display.innerHTML += button.innerHTML;
    })
  });

  operationButtons.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log(display.innerHTML)

      if(display.innerHTML=="") return;

      display.innerHTML += item.innerHTML;
    })
  });
}

displayValue();
```